# OPEN option is not coming in Kendo Export to Excel using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, export-to-excel

I have a jquery function that exports the kendo grid data in a excel. I am able to export the data but I want a OPEN option along with SAVE and CANCEL once the excel is exported. Check the attached image for reference.

[image]

Here is my Jquery code to export data:

```
exportResultToExcel: function (data) {
       
            if (data.length > 0) {
                var rows = [{
                    cells: [
                        { value: "Payer", background: "#1F497D", color: "#fff" },
                        { value: "Acc No.", background: "#1F497D", color: "#fff" },
                        { value: "Draft No.", background: "#1F497D", color: "#fff" },
                        
                    ]
                }];
                for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                    var dataItem = data[i];
                    rows.push({
                        cells: [
                          { value: dataItem.Customer },
                          { value: dataItem.AcNo) },
                          { value: dataItem.DtNo },
                        ]
                    })
                }
                var workbook = new kendo.ooxml.Workbook({
                    sheets: [
                      {
                          columns: [
                            { autoWidth: false },
                            { autoWidth: false },
                            { autoWidth: false },
                          ],
                          rows: rows
                      }
                    ]
                });
                var sheet = workbook.options.sheets[0];                              
                kendo.saveAs({ dataURI: workbook.toDataURL(), fileName: "Export Result.xlsx" });
            }

        })
    },
```

Answer (score 0):

The download and the options are handled by the browser. It's depending on the browsers how it shows up.

IE's default is to show "save" and depending on the security settings have have an option for "Save as" and "Save and Open".
[image: IE File example]

While Chrome downloads the file without any kind of message before hand. Once the file is downloaded it has options to "Open", "Always opens files of this type", and "Show in folder".
[image: Chrome file example]